# multiple regex replacement on variable in bash?

Tags: regex, bash

I'd like to know if there's a way to make multilple regexp replacements in bash with
${string//substring/replacement} or, possibly, what better solution exists.

I have a script to send updates to statusnet and friendika with curl. 
I sign petitions online, for instance, and am offered to tweet them, but would rather send to identica. I'm tired of pasting stuff and having to edit in terminal to escape @ and #, ! and ?.
I'd like to regexp replace them in my script to automagically change

```
@repbunghole and @SenatorArsehat Stop farking around with #someship! Do you want me to come smack you? | http://someshort.url
```

to

```
\@repbunghole \@SenatorArsehat Stop farking around with \#someship\! Do you want me to come smack you\? \| http://someshort.url
```

I do not have strong sed or awk fu, but imagine they may offer solutions, and I don't know how to use sed without writing the variable to a file, reading the file and acting on it, then setting the var with var=$(cat file).  Yes. I'm pretty new at this stuff.
I'm not finding sufficient data with the above ${string//substring/replacement/} for multiple replacements.  Running that X times to escape X different characters seems inefficient.

like

```
read -p "Enter a string: " a
b=${a//\@/\\\@}
c=${b//\#/\\\#}
d=${c//\!/\\\!}
e=${d//\?/\\\?}
f=${e//\"/\\\"}
g=${f//\'/\\\'}
```

etc., etc.
works in the meantime, but it's ugly...

Answer (score 8):

That's what [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) are for:

```
b=${a//[@#!?"']/\\\0}
```

Answer (score 4):

for "multiple regex replacement on variable in bash?"

both sed and awk can do it.
e.g I want to replace

```
a->1
b->2
c->3
```

with **sed**:

```
kent$  v=abc
kent$  newV=$(sed -e's/a/1/; s/b/2/; s/c/3/' <<< $v)
kent$  echo $newV2
123
```

with **awk**:

```
kent$  v=abc
kent$  newV2=$(awk '{gsub(/a/,"1");gsub(/b/,"2");gsub(/c/,"3")}1' <<< $v)                                                                
kent$  echo $newV                                                        
123
```